Verfiy a track using Spotify Api
i want to search and verify a track using the spotify API , when i make the call of this url:https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Shape of You&type=track ,with adding in the headers  the authorization code received by sending a post request using the clientid and client secret i get the access token and i get the result of the track in my example shape of you , the problem when i want to create a microservice that it will make the verification of any track using the spotify api it give me always please sign in and login with Oauth 2.0  ,
i have used the feign interface  like this way :
 @FeignClient(name = "spotify-client", url = "https://api.spotify.com")
 public interface SpotifyClient {

 @GetMapping("/v1/search")
 SongVerificationResponse searchSong(@RequestParam("q") String query, 
 @RequestParam("type") 
 String type,@RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorization);

 }
and the controller like this way :
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("/verification")
 public class VerificationController {

 @Autowired
 private SpotifyClient spotifyClient;

 @GetMapping("/verify-song")
 public ResponseEntity<String> verifySong(@RequestParam("songName") String songName) {
    try {
        String query = songName.replace(" ", "%20");
        String token = "BQCr- xxxxxxx";
        String authorizationHeader = "Bearer " + token;
        System.out.println("authorizationHeader: " + authorizationHeader);
        SongVerificationResponse verificationResponse = spotifyClient.searchSong(query, 
    "track",authorizationHeader);

        if (verificationResponse.isValid()) {
            String coverPhotoUrl = verificationResponse.getCoverPhotoUrl();
            return ResponseEntity.ok(coverPhotoUrl);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Invalid song");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error occurred 
   while verifying song");
    }
  }
so how i can let my microservice when i access from postman using this url 
http://localhost:8080/verification/verify-song?songName=Shape of You to get the result of 
this track ?

